# Ad Exchange Seller REST API and API Key

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-authentication

Can I reach to Ad Exchange Seller REST API just with API Key. I am using Google.Apis.AdExchangeSeller.v2_0 package with c#. My code is like folllowing

```
var service = new AdExchangeSellerService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
   ApplicationName = "Abc Client",
   ApiKey = "[MY APP KEY]",
});

var accounts = service.Accounts.List().Execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  APIKEY is used for public data only.

Ad Exchange Seller REST API  requires [Accounts: list](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/seller-rest/reference/v2.0/accounts/list#auth) states at the top that it requires Authorization.

> Authorization
>
> This request requires authorization with at least one of the following
>   scopes (read more about authentication and authorization).
>
> Scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adexchange.seller
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adexchange.seller.readonly

You will need to authenticate in order to use it.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to set authentication token lifetime.

Comment: When you authenticate with Oauth2.  You get a refresh token back, that refresh token lets you get new access tokens. Access tokens  are used to access a users data.  Access tokens expire after about an hour. Refreshtokens only expire if the user removes your authentication.  You cant change any of that.

Comment: Take a look in our https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth page for more details about authorized calling using the client library.